# Using $merge in Document-based aggregation pipeline is not working

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation

I have a collection, which I would like to perform an aggregation on and put the result into a separate collection in the same database. While scrutinizing the docs, I stumbled upon `$merge` which works exactly the way I want. I came up with the following mongo shell pipeline, which works flawlessly.

```js
db.getCollection('SOURCE_COLLECTION').aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {type: 'ABC'}
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "OUTPUT_COLLECTION",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

Now, I need the same effect in Spring boot, for which I have come up with the following, which theoretically should be no different.

```java
final ArrayList<Document> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();

pipeline.add(Document.parse("{$match: {type: 'ABC'}}"));
pipeline.add(Document.parse("{$merge: {into: 'OUTPUT_COLLECTION', whenMatched: 'replace'}}"));

mongoTemplate.getDb()
    .getCollection("SOURCE_COLLECTTION", Document.class)
    .aggregate(pipeline);
```

Nonetheless, this ain't working. As it can bee seen, I am using `MongoCollection<T>.aggregate()` method, which takes a `List<Document>` as a pipeline. Each stage in the pipeline is generated by parsing a JSON string into a document.

Interestingly, when I replace merging with `$out`, it works without any issue.

```java
final ArrayList<Document> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();

pipeline.add(Document.parse("{$match: {type: 'ABC'}}"));
pipeline.add(Document.parse("{$out: 'OUTPUT_COLLECTION'}"));

mongoTemplate.getDb()
    .getCollection("SOURCE_COLLECTTION", Document.class)
    .aggregate(pipeline);
```

But this is no good to me, as this aggregation will be executed multiple times (actually I am trying to populate a materialised view kind of a collection here). I'd need `$merge` to work, but it doesn't. What am I missing? Can someone see something that I haven't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the method `aggregate(pipeline)` does not behave like a terminal operation, when `$merge` is used in the pipeline. For the merger to work, some operation like `void toCollection()` or `void forEach(Consumer<? extends T> consumer)` should be invoked. So, invoking `toCollection()` on return from `aggregate()` did the trick.

```java
final ArrayList<Document> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();

pipeline.add(Document.parse("{$match: {type: 'ABC'}}"));
pipeline.add(Document.parse("{$out: 'OUTPUT_COLLECTION'}"));

mongoTemplate.getDb()
    .getCollection("SOURCE_COLLECTTION", Document.class)
    .aggregate(pipeline)
    .toCollection(); // This invocation completes the pipeline when it ends with $merge.
```

Interestingly, nothing of this sort is mentioned in documents it seems (at least not in any that I could find). I am not sure if this is the expected behaviour even.

Comment: i've encountered the same behavior when i use $merge as the last stage in a pipeline. Without a terminating invokation of any method (i used `.count()` ) after `.aggregate`. the pipeline simply does not execute.